# Use custom declarative activity in State Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to add a custom activity declared in xaml to a state machine. The activity is contained in the same project/assembly as the original state machine.
When I try to do it, a Visual Studio popup error appears:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Is it a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should just work. I would check the you custom XAML activity for issues.